GIMP keeps opening on the wrong monitor and can't be resized to fit on main monitor
This first happened when I swapped monitors for a different set. When I launch GIMP it always opens on my 2nd monitor and not the main. Main monitor is a 32" with 16:10 aspect ratio. 2nd is a 19" at 5:4. (Previous setup had monitors of the same aspect ratio and did not have this issue.)
The splash screen for GIMP shows on the main monitor and then the program launches on the 2nd.

Attempts to move it to the main monitor end up with the bottom of the program being off the screen and when maximized it takes up 80% of the screen and still hangs off the bottom.

(In above pics, menu bar is only 1 row wide on main monitor. The black below that is non-existent.)
Is there a way to force GNOME to forget window positions? The "center new windows" tweak does not work, it only centers it on the 2nd and all issues remain. Is there a way to force a window to open on a certain monitor (preferably without additional software or a huge script)?

Which version of Gimp and how did you install it?

GIMP 2.10.30(-1ubuntu0.1) installed via Synaptic, not a snap package.

Gimp can be asked to remember window position across sessions:

This said, I can always move a windows (Gimp or other) using Alt-drag, and once I have a top corner in reach, drag that corner to reduce window size.

I had to reset positions and then save them again once it loaded on the right monitor. Resizing the window before this only changed width, not height, so the bottom was still cut off. It was a strange issue.

Try Gimp3 instead. Since it uses GTK3, it would have a better window manager support.
If you are using Ubuntu 22.04 or 20.04, use the gimp3 ppa.
First remove the existing package and dependencies.
sudo apt remove gimp
sudo apt autoremove

Now add the Gimp PPA
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mati75/gimp30
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp

In Ubuntu 24.04, the PPA package is buggy. Use flatpak instead.
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak install --user https://flathub.org/beta-repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref 


I'll keep this in mind, but trying to limit the number of PPAs and development stage programs I'm running. Currently GIMP3 is at development 2.99.18. Should only be a few more months before 3.0.0 comes out.

Gimp3 is mostly bug free. I have been using it for the last five years. I urge you to give it a try. No one knows when 3.0.0 will be released

But Gimp3 is pretty much devoid of 3rd-party scripts and plugins.
